# Magento store id in cronjob

Tags: magento, parameters, cron, store

Is there a way to give a store id as parameter when executing a model with cronjob ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot specify store scope for Magento Cron Job, but you can add additional arguments that you can use inside of it.

1. Specify additional node that you can process via your cron method:

   ```
   <crontab>
      <jobs>
          <job_name>
              <schedule>
                  <cron_expr>* * * * * *</cron_expr>     
              </schedule>
              <run>
                  <model>module/observer::myJob</model>
              </run>
              <store>store_code</store>
          </job_name>
      </jobs>
   </crontab>
   ```
2. And method where you receiving the schedule object with current job code:

   ```
   public function myJob($schedule) 
   {
       $jobsRoot = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('crontab/jobs');
       $jobConfig = $jobsRoot->{$schedule->getJobCode()};
       $yourStoreNode = (string) $jobConfig->store;

       // Here goes store related functionality
   }
   ```

All the store related models can load data only for a particular store, so I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: quite old answer, but I will try anyway...Magento 1.7, $schedule for me is null. Which version are you using? Any hints?

Comment: Check cron_schedule table in mysql, does it have entries?

Comment: What is the procedure for M2 ?