# Magento Cronjob withTransactional Email

Tags: magento, cron, transactional-email

I have a question about transactional emails in Magento 1.7.

If a cronjob is sending the transactional emails its using the wrong theme/templates (base/default). But I want to use my own temples in my own themefolder.

How can I set it to the right tehme?

Comment: something like `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);` ?

Comment: Take a look @

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015469/getting-storeid-in-a-cron-job

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673911/magento-store-id-in-cronjob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tims answer solved it.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
```